# Is there any way to disconnect or end call in ios (Swift or Objective-C)

Tags: ios, call, telephony, disconnect

I want to develop an application where the call should disconnect automatically. can anyone please tell me how to achieve this programatically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is not allowing access to call, than also u want more info just go through ctcallcenter framework